# Disable Ubercart "empty cart" confirmation

Tags: ubercart

My ubercart link uses the -e flag to empty the cart before adding a new item. Users can only purchase one item, it is a subscription site.

If there was something in their cart, ubercart displays a "this action cannot be undone" message and a confirmation button. How to I disable that functionality? (Note: I'm a beginner ;)

I tried using the Drupal disable messages module but it did not work on that message.

I would appreciate your expert information, solutions or guidance.

Thank you!